# AttributeError when importing flask-WTF

Tags: python

**The error:**

```
E:\wamp64\www\Flask_Blog>python flaskblog.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "flaskblog.py", line 2, in <module>
    from forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm
  File "E:\wamp64\www\Flask_Blog\forms.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
  File "E:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\flask_wtf-0.14.2-py3.8.egg\flask_wtf\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .recaptcha import *
  File "E:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\flask_wtf-0.14.2-py3.8.egg\flask_wtf\recaptcha\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .fields import *
  File "E:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\flask_wtf-0.14.2-py3.8.egg\flask_wtf\recaptcha\fields.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .validators import Recaptcha
  File "E:\Program Files\Python\lib\site-packages\flask_wtf-0.14.2-py3.8.egg\flask_wtf\recaptcha\validators.py", line 2, in <module>
    import urllib2 as http
  File "E:\Program Files\Python\lib\urllib2.py", line 254
    raise AttributeError, attr
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

**My code:**
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
```

I have tried reinstalling the package.

The error is exactly the same when i run it with py - 3

[image: The error is exactly the same when i run it with py - 3]

Comment: Also, are you trying to run this on Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I am running this on Python 3

Comment: Could you try instead: `python3 flaskblog.py`

Comment: I just tried, I am still getting the same error...

Comment: Hm, ok. In Python 3 there should *not* be a `urllib2.py` so that's interesting...

Comment: Just want to clarify, so the error is not caused by a mistake on my end but a bug in the library? 

If so, what is a possible work around it?

Comment: Well, I'm not quite sure what's going on when you run it with Python 3. Can you post the full traceback of that error?

Comment: The error is exactly the same.

Comment: This looks like you installed python2 and python3 to the same directory -- I'd suggest uninstalling both and then only installing python 3

Comment: also don't use `easy_install`, it's super deprecated -- use `pip install ...` instead

Comment: @AnthonySottile: aha! Thank you for weighing in! That makes a lot of sense.

Comment: You're right, i uninstalled python on my computer and reinstalled python 3. I suspect when i upgraded from python2 to 3, some of py2 files remained...

Comment: Thank you both for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. Please tell us if it works when you have a clean installation.

Comment: it's working :) thank you all